# remove jsessionid after logout in spring security + angularjs application

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-security

I have a question:
I am developing a spring + angularjs based application and when I log in there is a jsession id that does not disappear after logout and I can log in with a random password. I suppose it has something to do with the jsessionid because it is not removed after logout. I am using spring security for this purpose. Is there an easy way to prevent saving jsessionid on the client side?

here is my config() method in the SpringConfig class:

```
    @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/users").permitAll().and()
            .antMatcher("/user").formLogin().and().httpBasic().and()
            .logout().deleteCookies("remove").invalidateHttpSession(true);
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: not very clear how you are able to login with the random password even if you have the sessionid